# Black display after wake from suspend via closing the lid

Tags: 14.04, ati, graphics, power-management, suspend

I have bought a new HP 15-G002AX notebook recently, with

> Processor: AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics × 4
>
> Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on my system dual-booted along with Windows 8.1

When I try to suspend the laptop using the lid, and try to resume back, it just shows a black screen and I have no other option left, have to shut it down with brute force (pressing the power key for long).

Why am I seeing this error? Is it due to my Graphics or anything else.

I have searched a lot on different forums, but I'm not able to find a pre ise solution to this. I want to be able to put it on sleep and wake up easily :)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

i changed my video driver to solve this problem.

System Settings-> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers.

I was using the X.Org X server Video driver for "AMD/ATI display".
I switched to the AMD graphics accelrators from fglrx-updates.

my video card is Radeon HD 6480G(Asus laptop)

Comment: I had the same problem on a Lenovo W510. I changed from the default driver (X.Org X Server Nouveau) to Nvidia Binary driver 331.113. We'll see if it makes any different the next time the system sleeps.

Answer (score -1):

I posted this answer elswhere it worked for me and may help you as well.

I am using a dell d430 with ubuntu 14.04. I was having this problem as well. After some tinkering I found a simple solution for the Dell computer and there should be a similar solution with other laptops as well. When I get the black screen after suspend I use the special function key (the key with the Blue Fn on it) and the f7 on the dell this has a blue picture of a monitor on it. press and hold the fn key and hit the monitor key (f7 in the case of the Dell) and the screen comes back on. No need to edit scripts or anything else. Hope this helps.